# Using NOW() in a select with Squeel

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, aggregate-functions, squeel

I want to get the average of the difference between the current time and a datetime value in the database with [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel):

```
Car.select{average(NOW() - created_at)}
```

Which tries to take "NOW" as a column in the database:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column cars.NOW does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT avg("cars"."NOW" - "cars"."created_at") FROM "cars"  ...
```

Any way to do this in Squeel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Ernie Miller's answer here: https://github.com/ernie/squeel/issues/112

`Car.select{average(now.func - created_at)}`